# Can not click on the PayPal button inside the iframe - Cypress

Tags: iframe, paypal, cypress

I am writing e2e Testcases on Cypress for webshop, we have integrated PayPal and I am unable to click on the PayPal button with in the iframe.
I always get an error in finding the element in iframe.
someone have an idea how can I do that?

code

```
  cy.get('iframe')
        .getframe3D()
        .find('paypal-button-number-0')
```

Command

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getframe3D', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
        $iframe.ready(function() {
          resolve($iframe.contents().find('body'));
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please post the errors that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with iframe is quite tricky in Cypress however it's possible. Your custom command looks correct and it worked for me as well. However, you can also try below way and check if it is working for you.

Here provide CSS selector for the iframe as an argument getIframeBody() function.

```js
cy.getIframeBody('iframe').find('paypal-button-number-0').click()
```

Custom Commands

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', (iframe) => {
  return cy.get(iframe).then($iframe => {
    const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
    cy.wrap($body)
  })
})
```

For more info you can follow the [cypress blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/) to interact with iFrame

Answer (score 0):

Your custom command to get the iframe body is fine, you just have the wrong selector for the button.

Since it's a class, you need a `.` prefix

```js
cy.get('iframe')
  .getframe3D()
  .find('.paypal-button-number-0')
```